# .NET Core: "Unable to materialize entity instance of type 'IdentityUser'. No discriminators matched the discriminator value"

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dbcontext, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm creating a Profile for a user, adding columns to ApplicationUser and then executing the DbSet command at ApplicationDbContext. Just writing the DbSet command, it will throw an error:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to materialize entity instance of
> type 'IdentityUser'. No discriminators matched the discriminator value
> ''.

What did I do wrong and where? How can I fix it? Just dropping DbSet at ApplicationDbContex, everything can run normally.

[image]

Code of the ApplicationUser:

```cs
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Display(Name = "Full Name")] public string FullName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdateAt { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        CreateAt = DateTime.Now;
        UpdateAt = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

The ApplicationDbConText:

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should see this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0#custom-user-data).

Answer (score 7):

It seems that you're missing the `ApplicationUser` as a generic argument for your context.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
```

See more in detail: [Customize identity model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: I tried but it didn't seem to work so I came here to ask everyone.

Comment: @SinLee You have to specify it anyway. Did you mention ApplicationUser class anywhere else? For example in services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser>?

Comment: @feihoa I use services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
                 .AddDefaultUI()
                 .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
                 .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

Comment: @SinLee Try services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole> instead. And be sure that your _userManager instance is an instance of UserManager<ApplicationUser> class.

Comment: @feihoa I run everything normally, Login, Register. I just called it out to show more info on Profile and got this error

Comment: @feihoa I just deleted the data in the database and it succeeded without changing anything ...

Comment: @SinLee That's weird, but ok

Comment: Since it might be useful for others. If deleting the data in your database solved the problem you might have had an inheritance chain mapped to a database. You have the option to map all to the same table with a discriminator or map the hierarchy to separate tables. The discriminator column is used to identify which type in your inheritance chain that the row belongs to. If that field is for some reason empty (e.g. if you would create the super type and add it to the db) then you would also get the error you experienced.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help at all. I just tried creating an extension table for IdentityUsers after having created a test user in the database; ran into this error, and when I checked the database it added a Discriminator attribute to the IdentityUser table. So for my test user I put "IdentityUser" in as the discriminator and it loaded the page up perfectly fine. It might be because that user was logged in and it couldn't load the default unlogged in page, but figured I would throw that out there.

My assumption is that it was trying to load the user, but it didn't know how to handle a blank discriminator spot and it doesn't assign a default discriminator value to previously created users.

Comment: This simple solution worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I face this exception too. To fix it, simply I go to my database open the table which contains “Discriminator” column and delete the records and run the application. Rest things are handled by Entity framework .I hope this will work for you as well.

Answer (score 1):

The discussion is really old, but I had the same error, I found that discussion, it put me on the way, but required more research to find the solution to my problem, I'll just explain the way I solved my problem.

When you add your own user class to your project, the user class is often rename `ApplicationUser`, a class that's inheriting the `IdentityUser`, before making any migration, you have to go in the `ApplicationDbContext` file, and add it as a generic argument for the context:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
```

after that you have always to make some changes in the `_LoginPartial.cshtml` file (`Views > Shared > _LoginPartial.cshtml`) in changing these lines :

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager
```

by those

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using YourProjectName.Data
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
```

*Don't forget to replace **YourProjectName** by the name of your project*

After that you must go in the `Program.cs` File and replace the `IdentityUser` at line `13` :

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

remplace the reference to the `IdentityUser` by the `ApplicationUser` reference, it should look like that :

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

And if you have a `Startup.cs` file in your project, you should make some changes a well, at line `41` you'll find there the following line :

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
   .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
 .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

replace the instruction by the following :

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
   options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
})
   .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
 .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
   .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

don't forget to remove spaces between some instructions I pasted, here.

more details in that [course](https://openclassrooms.com/fr/courses/5671596-kick-start-your-mvc-application-with-asp-net-core/6430840-update-your-database-with-code-first-migrations), and in the [ASP.NET Core Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

What I write was Already written, here or other discussion, I just tried to put together all those answers and tried to add some precisions, the link gave by **@feihoa** really helped me. I hope my answer will help anyone.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

In your Startup.cs or Program.cs (it depends whether you
use ASP.NET Core 6.x or earlier).

Change this:

`builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>`

To this:

`builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>`

Do not forget. In addition to modify that in your `Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml`:

Those:

`@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager`

`@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager`

To those:

`@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager`

`@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager`

Answer (score 0):

When registering check if email is unique, Example

```
var emailAlreadyUsed = _userManager.Users.Any(x => x.Email == user.Email);
if (emailAlreadyUsed){
    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Email already used");
    return Page();
}
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
```