# Problem with adding ASP.NET Core IdentityUser in my project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I added Identity into my project and I modified `Register.cshtml.cs` file where I added role manager variable. It looks sometimg like this:

```
 private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
.
.
.
 public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            if (!_roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(Roles.Role_Admin).GetAwaiter().GetResult())
            {
                _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(Roles.Role_Admin)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(Roles.Role_Customer)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
        }
```

I also added `ApplicationUser.cs` class that looks like this:

```
 public class ApplicationUser:IdentityUser
    {
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }   
        public string? Address { get; set; }
        public string? Town { get; set; }
        public int? ZipCode { get; set; }
        public string? Phone { get; set; }
        public string? Comment { get; set; }

    }
```

In `Program.cs` I added service like this:

```
builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser,IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true).AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DBContext>();
```

Now when i start my application i get this error:

```
InvalidOperationException: Unable to materialize entity instance of type 'IdentityUser'. No discriminators matched the discriminator value ''.
lambda_method14(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext , SingleQueryResultCoordinator )
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable<T>+AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync<TSource>(IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync<TSource>(IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager<TUser>.ValidateSecurityStampAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator<TUser>.ValidateAsync(CookieValidatePrincipalContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler<TOptions>.AuthenticateAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, string scheme)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Here is my dbcontext file:

```
{
    public DBContext(DbContextOptions<DBContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
    public DbSet<Category> categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> products { get; set; }    
    public DbSet<CoverType> coverTypes { get; set; }  
    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> applicationUsers { get; set; }
```

Do I need to add something in `Program.cs` file or change the type of user?

Comment: Could you show the details of your dbcontext?

Comment: I changed my post and added `dbcontext.cs` file

Comment: Unable to reporeduce, here's a related issue,hopes help:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68196099/net-core-unable-to-materialize-entity-instance-of-type-identityuser-no-dis